# java quartz scheduler run at specific time which comes from Oracle table

Tags: java, oracle

For example, I want to write a Java program to send an email at each day and time comes from database column.

For example

I have a database table called scheduler

Id ,StartTime and emailid are fields of the table

So i want to run java program from Oracle database Starttime column and send the email to respective email id.

how can I use Quartz scheduler to achieve this?

Comment: you can do this with spring boot + quartz, follow the below link and update the time as needed.
https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-quartz-scheduler-email-scheduling-example/

Comment: Can we achieve this normal java program?